# Ajax Post parameters

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I have a script that posts data to a php script:

```
xhr.open("POST","processData.php");
```

And i am sending once piece of data to it:

```
xhr.send(email);
```

How would a post multiple peice of data to the php scrip? Lets say i have the variable first and last name that i want to sent to be processed? I've tried this:

xhr.send(essay, firstName);

But not sure what to do with it in the PHP script, do i use the usual $_POST['essay'] to collect the values? what about encoding aswell?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create an object, and send that:

```
var obj = {
    essay: essay,
    firstName: firstName
};
xhr.send("data=" + JSON.stringify(obj));
```

On server side you get:

```
json_decode($_POST['data']); //Gives you a standard object with fields essay and firstName
```

Comment: So what happens when i use json_decode($_POST['data']); in php? how do i get the firstname and email into separation variables? isn't there a way i can send both pieces of data separate like i would generally in PHP?

Comment: There is, you can do: `xhr.send("essay=" + JSON.stringify(essay) + "&firstName=" + JSON.stringify(firstName));`. But doing the thing above, you can have: `$result = json_decode($_POST['data']);` and then access `$result->essay` and `$result->firstName`.

Comment: You mean why prefer the `json_decode` way? because the JS side is more readable and also it preserves the nature of data being sent as a single entity.

Answer (score 2):

just create the querystring to pass along `send()`

```
xhr.send("essay=" + encodeURIComponent(essay) 
          + "&firstname=" + encodeURIComponent(firstName));
```

About encodeURIComponent you can see th [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):  it could be necessary use it if your variables contain uncommon chars like spaces, ampersands and other

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON (Javascript Object Notation):

http://www.json.org/

```
var data = new Object;
data.name = 'some name';
data.id = 123
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
```

You can turn this into an identical php object with json_decode().  The JS engine on current browsers has the JSON methods built in, but older IE's (6, 7) do not, so you need to include this script to compensate:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js